# Windows 7 chkdsk fails on restart with "chkdsk cancelled"

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I'm trying to sort out a problem on my wife's laptop. The event log has many errors:

```
The device, \Device\Hardisk0\DR0, has a bad block.
```

So, I'd like to run **chkdsk /r /f** on it. I do that in a CMD window (as an admin) to schedule chkdsk on restart. But when it restarts, it attempts to run that command, then stops with

```
chkdsk cancelled
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: chkdsk /r /f is redundant, /r switch implies /f, chkdsk /r will perform both functions.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to boot from a different device. In my case, I hunted out the Windows 7 upgrade disk, worked out how to get to a command prompt, and then chkdsk was able to run. That fixed my bad blocks (added them to the marked bad blocks list).

Comment: Back your data up and replace the drive or risk losing data.

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a `/x` option. It will force the disk to unmount first before scanning.

This could be the issue since `chkdsk` will cancel if the volume is in use.

`chkdsk /r /f /x`

Comment: No. That made no difference. Same message 'The disk check has been cancelled'.

Comment: Have you tried starting up in Safe Mode command line only and running the same command from there?

Comment: Safe Mode did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Bad block errors typically mean a failing harddrive. We immediately replace these in my practice as an IT consultant.

For a personal user, however, a chkdsk COULD buy you some time, but then again, it may not. I recommend replacement as soon as possible, and if you have data you need I would avoid using it more until you can get a good backup!